# Jsp Project not updating in eclipse using Jboss Server 5.0?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, eclipse-juno

I am working on a dynamic web project and using JSP .When I create a JSP file and run it on server it works fine. But as I update my JSP file (even small changes) that are not reflected on the running window. I have cleaned and restarted the server but the Output donot update accordingly . I am not getting how to work .(I executed my code with different file name it worked perfectly but if I use old name it doesnot work).

I am new to this Please help me and tell me where I am  going wrong. Please help?

Comment: are you changing some javascript or css in jsp files?
Sometimes browers may cache javascript resources for better performance.

Comment: I am doing that in Eclipse browser how to fix that An Idea?

Comment: I would recommend using an external browser so that you can use tools like firebug to inspect DOM API

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file {jbossroot}/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml

Change the property "deleteWorkDirOnContextDestroy" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens as the browser you test your page with caches the web page.

It happened to me too a few times and I fixed it with restarting the web browser, please try it and tell me if it did the trick.

Comment: I am doing that in Eclipse browser how to fix that An Idea?

Comment: If u make any Changes in css or javascript files,you should be stop the running server on eclipse. then clear all data on console, cookies of browser and etc,,. save all files  . then you start the server again and run the project.

Comment: @RameshJ That's why I always use an external browser ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First you stop the server. then remove your project from server. then compile your project. after that add to server and run.